# Why can't I see the source corresponding to my develop branch on Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have some little problem with Bitbucket and Git Flow. I have remote repo and I'm using Git Flow. When I make some changes in my `develop` branch, I stage them, commit, and then 
push them to the server using

```
git push origin develop
```

However, when I go have a look at the source corresponding to my `develop` branch on Bitbucket, there is nothing there. Why can't I see it? Perhaps that would require merging `develop` with `master`, but I want to use my `master` branch for releases only. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that you did successfully push your `develop` branch to your remote on Bitbucket, you should be able to view the source, but you need to switch the view to that branch. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Right under the "Source" heading, click the "master" button; you'll get a drop-down list of all the branches on that remote, and you should be able to select `develop`.